# Precise formulation of the ER = EPR conjecture

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, qft-in-curved-spacetime, wormholes, epr-experiment

Maldacena and Susskind have "formulated" the now famous [ER = EPR conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER_%3D_EPR) in their paper [*Cool horizons for entangled black holes*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533), but as of today, I have not find a quantum theorist who can precisely describe what Maldacena and Susskind actually mean (including Maldacena and Susskind).

[Quoting Peter Woit](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/wordpress/?p=13251):

> My problem with ER = EPR is not that it is untrue, but that it’s meaningless, as about “not even wrong” as “not even wrong” gets. It’s basically a conjecture that “maybe there is a duality between conventional QM and some unknown theory”, but doesn’t tell you what the unknown theory is (it’s not conventional GR).

Can anyone here formulate ER = EPR in a *precise* way ?

Comment: This seems really more opinion-based ...

Comment: ER=EPR does not have a precise formulation, however precise statements such as [Ryu-Takayanagi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryu%E2%80%93Takayanagi_conjecture) could be seen as realizations of a more general principle.